# Best way to save Web page settings for mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, local-storage, html, web-storage

I am going to be modifying a mobile Web page that offers various services.
I wish to make it so that the user can change what services can be accessed via settings that would be stored on the user's mobile device.
Please can somebody let me know what would be the best way to do so.
It would be mainly for iOS and Android devices.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just use cookies?

Comment: Hi, yes, I could just use cookies, but I just wanted to find out the best way.
Recently, along with the advancement of HTML5 there has been different storage methods being used which all must have a reason for being added.
If you are suggesting cookies as the best way, then thank you very much.